# How to identify the locking queries in SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

One database was having locking issues last night. Currently, I executed sp_who2 and sys.dm_exec_requests and did not find any active blocked transactions. How can I investigate in the database to identify the causes behind those locks?

Answer (score 0):

Historical long-term blocking information is not captured by default.

Consider setting the [blocked process threshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/blocked-process-threshold-server-configuration-option) configuration option. This will write a blocked process report to the SQL Server error log when blocking occurs longer than the number of seconds specified. The blocking information can also be captured by an Extended Events trace including the [block_process_report](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/dynamics365/no-audience/2015/01/16/using-sql-server-extended-events-to-produce-a-blocked-process-report/) event, which can be written to a target file for later analysis.